# Xcode 11 scenekit editor bug

Tags: xcode, scenekit

I am getting this weird graphical issue with xcode scenekit editor when ever I select an object. Is there a way to fix it?

[image]

xcode version: 11.3.1 (11C505)
macos version: 10.15.3 (19D76)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to a bug in the Metal GPU driver. As a workaround you can hide the grid or selection outline in the "Display options" menu (second icon from the right in the toolbar at the bottom of the view).